# Unhandled Exception: Stack Overflow , Flutter GetXController is being initialized for 2000 times

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm putting my GetXController only once on the home page  using :

```dart
class NewOrdersList extends StatelessWidget {

  final OrdersController ordersC = Get.put(OrdersController());
...
```

then whenever I need the controller I simply use

```dart
  OrdersController ordersC = Get.find();
```

and the controller itself:

```dart
  @override
  void onInit() {
    trackLocation();
    super.onInit();
  }
```

at the end of the function `trackLocation();` I use `OrdersController ordersC = Get.find();` because I need to access a variable inside the controller.

but when u launch the application I see that the controller has been initialized thousands of times.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your trackLocation function as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write `Get.find()` everytime if you are using controller in same class. If you need to access your `OrderController's` instance in some other class, then and only then you can use `Get.find`. And don't write `OrderController ordersC = Get.find()` after `trackLocation()`. Because once you initialize your controller (Either put or find) , then you can access all variables from it. Never initialize your controller multiple time in your code.